# unable to move opportunity information to merge fields of visualforce email template from apex trigger

Tags: email-template

I am sending emails(with visual force email template) to different levels of approvers present in opportunity record when every we click a button submit for approval. Our requirement is if a person 'A' is in  two levels on a record we need to send a single email to A. Below is my code. When ever I am click a button submit for approval I could see my visualforce template only in debug logs.

1. why i am not receiving any email?
2. I don't see any opportunity details(relatedto information) in that
   email template. Just it showing my visualforce hardcodes.

Can some one help me on this?

**Trigger:**

```
trigger opportunityemail on Opportunity(after update, after insert) {
    List emails = new List();
    set sendtoid = new set();
    list sendtoaddress = new list();
    list useremail = new list();
    for (opportunity op: trigger.new) {
        if (op.submitfor_approval__c == true) {
            sendtoid.add(op.Level1__c);
            sendtoid.add(op.Level2__c);
            sendtoid.add(op.Level3__c);
            system.debug('size of approvers:' + sendtoid.size());
        }
    }
    sendtoaddress = [select id, email from user where id in: sendtoid];
    for (user u: sendtoaddress) {
        useremail.add(u.email);
        system.debug('u.email:' + u.email);
        for (opportunity op: trigger.new) {
            if (op.submitfor_approval__c == true) {
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                mail.setTargetObjectId(u.id);
                system.debug('u.id:' + u.id);
                mail.setToAddresses(useremail);
                mail.setTemplateId('00Xc0000000ECDf');
                mail.saveAsActivity = false;

                emails.add(mail);
            }
        }
    }
    Messaging.sendEmail(emails);
}
```

**Visualforce template:**

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="opportunity approval needed" recipientType="user" relatedToType="Opportunity">
    <messaging:htmlEmailBody>
        <html>
        <body style="background-color:#E6E6FA">
            <img src="aprovalpic.gif" alt="need aproval" width="42" height="42"> </img>
            <STYLE type="text/css">
                TH {
                    font-size: 20px;
                    font-face: arial;
                    background: #CCCCCC;
                    border-width: 5;
                    text-align: center
                }
                TD {
                    font-size: 11px;
                    font-face: verdana
                }
                TABLE {
                    border: solid #CCCCCC;
                    border-width: 1
                }
                TR {
                    border: solid #CCCCCC;
                    border-width: 1
                }
                thead {
                    color: green;
                }
                tbody {
                    color: blue;
                }
                tfoot {
                    color: red;
                }
                empty-cells: hide;
                table,
                th,
                td {
                    border: 1px solid black;
                }
            </STYLE>
            <font face="arial" size="2">
                <p>Hi {!recipient.name}, </p>
                <pre>                                              SYS, INC  <br/>
  </pre>
                <b> General Information</b><br/> ******************************************************************************************************************** <br/><br/>
                <table border="0">
                    <colgroup>
                        <col span="2" style="background-color:red"> </col>
                        <col style="background-color:yellow"> </col>
                    </colgroup>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th> OPPORTUNITY DETAILS ARE HERE </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Opportunity name {!relatedTo.name} </th>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <th> amount {!relatedTo.amount} </th>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
                <p> <b>Below is a list of users need to approve: {!relatedTo.name}.</b></p>
                ******************************************************************************************************************** <br/><br/>
                <table border="0" class="tabel__1">
                    <tr>
                        <td>{!relatedTo.Level1__r.name}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{!relatedTo.level2__r.name}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{!relatedTo.level3__r.name}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{!relatedTo.PL_Level1__r.name}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{!relatedTo.PL_Level2__r.name}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{!relatedTo.Ps_Level2__r.name}</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>{!relatedTo.Level4__r.name}</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>{!relatedto.PL_Level2__r.name}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <p />
            </font>
            <p> Please go through below link to Accept/Reject this opportnunity.</p>
            <p><a href="http://cs14.force.com/ApprovalDetailscopy?id={!Relatedto.Id}&name={!recipient.name}">accept/reject here</a></p>
        </body>
        </html>
    </messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Comment: I made change. But still not receiving any email. And my visualforce template not providing recipients name. example :if use user id, I could see "Hi AAABB" . If I use contact id "Hi     ". Please help me how can I achieve this?

Comment: @ Santanu Boral   for(user u:sendtoaddress){  
   useremail.add(u.email);
   system.debug('u.email:' +u.email);
   for(opportunity op:trigger.new){
   if(op.submitfor_approval__c == true){
   Messaging.SingleEmailMessage  mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
   mail.setTargetObjectId('003c000000ikhk2');
   system.debug('u.id:' +u.id);
   mail.setToAddresses(useremail);
   mail.setTemplateId('00Xc0000000ECDf');
   mail.setWhatId(op.id); 
   mail.saveAsActivity = false;
   emails.add(mail);
     }
}
}
Messaging.sendEmail(emails);

} still  not receiving email.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(op.submitfor_approval__c == true) { 
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); 
    system.debug('u.id:' +u.id); 
    mail.setToAddresses(useremail); 
    mail.setTemplateId('00Xc0000000ECDf'); 
    mail.saveAsActivity = false; emails.add(mail); 
    mail.setWhatId(op.id); 

    //WhatId cannot be set unless target object id is contact
    //Get any contact from org and use it as you are already using User's emails all users will get email.
    mail.setTargetObjectId(contact.id); 

    //Now this method will ensure that contact will not receive any emails 
    setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient(false);
}
```

Comment: Added an edit for code blocks, you might want to take the comments and form an actual answer with it though so readers don't have to browse the code.